# Backing up database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spatial-database, boundless-suite

I need to create a backup from my database (in PostgreSQL 9.3). I have used the pg_dump tool, gives me an error. I have also used pgAdmin III for backing up which also gives me the following error:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  could not load library
>   "C:/Program Files/Boundless/OpenGeo/bin/../pgsql/lib/postgis-2.1.dll":
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I tried checking the path but I couldn't find it. The nearest path that I reach is:

> "C:/Program Files/Boundless/OpenGeo/bin"

Comment: Is this a flat table or does it have some sort of join on it?

Answer (score 1):

Path should be due to the ../ in the path name

```
"C:/Program Files/Boundless/OpenGeo/pgsql/lib/"
```

But as stated in your first question, create a copy of the "data" dir of PostgreSQL. Then undo the tutorial you followed, by deleting the files you added to PostgreSQL,  then restart postgresql and try again.

If this does not work, then you might be best of uninstalling PostgreSQL, reinstall it and insert the copy of the "data" dir into the new installation.

Also you should use the Stack Builder to install PostGIS and pgRouting.